# Surely there is a better grid than DataGrid for the .NET Compact Framework

Tags: compact-framework, datagrid

Having spent a couple of days wrestling with DataGrid in .NET CF, especially controlling the look and feel, I'm looking for alternatives.  I don't mind purchasing a solution.

I'm looking for

1. Redistributable to our enterprise customers.  We control the hardware so it doesn't have to work perfectly on every device.
2. Display strings and numbers in columns with headings.
3. Scrollable, but no paging.  Don't row editing.  Need to add and delete rows.
4. User re-sizable column widths, and a way to persist that.
5. Work with .NET CF 2.0 or 3.5 on Windows CE 6.0

Any suggestions on grids or toolkits?

Answer (score 0):

What about using the SmartGrid?
http://www.resco.net/developer/mobileformstoolkit/smartgrid.aspx

Michael

Comment: I saw that - is it good?  I would prefer not purchasing the whole toolkit ideally, but it doesn't seem like that is an option.